Как написать скрипт, который при наборе текста в инпуте input#name-input подставляет его текущее значение в span#name-output как имя приветствия


<input type="text" id="name-input" placeholder="Please enter your name" />
<h1>Hello, <span id="name-output">Anonymous</span>!</h1>



Напиши скрипт, который при наборе текста в инпуте input#name-input (событие input) подставляет его текущее значение в span#name-output как имя приветствия. Обязательно очищай значение в инпуте по краям от пробелов. Если инпут пуст или содержит только пробелы, вместо имени у спан должна подставляться строка "Anonymous".
Hello, Anonymous!

Ваши попытки будут?

@SwaD, а зачем?

@Qwertiy спасибо! Теперь есть понимание. Ещё попробую доработать это: "...или содержит только пробелы, вместо имени у спан должна подставляться..."

@IванПрисяжнюк, исправил.



document.getElementById('name-input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.getElementById('name-output').textContent = e.target.value.trim() || "Anonymous"
})
<input type="text" id="name-input" placeholder="Please enter your name" />
<h1>Hello, <span id="name-output">Anonymous</span>!</h1>



